# Constant Assignment Bug in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

We caught some code in Ruby that seems odd, and I was wondering if someone could explain it:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> APPLE = 'aaa'
=> "aaa"
irb(main):002:0> banana = APPLE
=> "aaa"
irb(main):003:0> banana << 'bbb'
=> "aaabbb"
irb(main):004:0> banana
=> "aaabbb"
irb(main):005:0> APPLE
=> "aaabbb"
```

Catch that? The constant was appended to at the same time the local variable was.

Known behavior? Expected?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977780/what-does-ruby-constant-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Catch that? The constant was appended to at the same time the local variable was.

No, it wasn't appended to, and neither was the local variable.

The *single* object that *both* the constant and the local variable are referring to was appended to, but neither the constant nor the local variable was changed. You cannot modify or change a variable or constant in Ruby (at least not in the way that your question implies), the only thing you *can* change is objects.

The only two things you *can* do with variables or constants is dereferencing them and assigning to them.

The constant is a red herring here, it is completely irrelevant to the example given. The only thing that is relevant is that there is only *one* single object in the entire example. That single object is accessible under two different names. If the object changes, then the object changes. Period. It does not mysteriously split itself in two. Which name you use to look at the changed object doesn't matter. There is only one object anyway.

This works exactly the same as in any other programming language: if you have multiple references to a mutable object in, say, Python, Java, C#, C++, C, Lisp, Smalltalk, JavaScript, PHP, Perl or whatever, then any change to that object will be visible no matter what reference is used, even if some of those references are `final` or `const` or whatever that particular language calls it.

This is simply how shared mutable state works and is just one of the many reasons why shared mutable state is bad.

In Ruby, you can generally call the `freeze` method on any object to make it immutable. However, again, you are modifying the *object* here, so anybody else who has a reference to that object will all the sudden find that the object has become immutable. Therefore, just to be safe, you need to copy the object first, by calling `dup`. But of course, that's not enough either, if you think of an array, for example: if you `dup` the array, you get a different *array*, but the objects *inside* the array are the still the same ones in the original array. And if you `freeze` the array, then you can no longer modify the *array*, but the objects *in* the array may very well still be mutable:

```
ORIG = ['Hello']
CLONE = ORIG.dup.freeze
CLONE[0] << ', World!'
CLONE # => ['Hello, World!']
```

That's shared mutable state for you. The only way to escape this madness is either to give up shared state (e.g. Actor Programming: if nobody else can see it, then it doesn't matter how often or when it changes) or mutable state (i.e. Functional Programming: if it never changes, then it doesn't matter how many others see it).

The fact that one of the two variables in the original example is actually a constant is completely irrelevant to the problem. There two main differences between a variable and a constant in Ruby: they have different lookup rules, and constants generate a warning if they are assigned to more than once. But in this example, the lookup rules are irrelevant and the constant is assigned to only once, so there really is no difference between a variable and a constant in this case.

Comment: Can you deference variables / constants in ruby, or can you only assign them to nil?

Comment: Also, if an object is created and it isn't assigned to anything, does it exist until it gets garbage collected?

Comment: @myself: [Is it possible to undefine a variable in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339181/is-it-possible-to-undefine-a-variable-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

Known behaviour. Constants don't mean that you can't modify the object it refers to, merely that it'll give you a warning (and only a warning) if you assign it to a different object.

In short, ruby constants aren't.

**Note**: This behaviour is listed in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372652/what-are-the-ruby-gotchas-a-newbie-should-be-warned-about/392795#392795) to "What are the Ruby Gotchas a newbie should be warned about?" It's a worthwhile read.

Comment: They're basically constant *references*.  Java works basically the same way.

Comment: @Benjamin Oakes: Yes, exactly. And not only Java, but basically any programming language on the planet. Although in Ruby, they are not even that constant: re-assigning them will only generate a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag:  Very true.  If anyone is aware of a way to force an exception when re-assigning constants, I'd be very interested.  The facility of freezing objects is quite helpful though.

Comment: I made a question from my last comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023617/throw-exception-when-re-assigning-a-constant-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze constants if you want them to be unchangable:

```
>> APPLE = 'aaa'
=> "aaa"
>> banana = APPLE
=> "aaa"
>> APPLE.freeze
=> "aaa"
>> banana.frozen?
=> true
>> banana << 'bbb'
TypeError: can't modify frozen string
    from (irb):5:in `<<'
    from (irb):5
```

Comment: No, you can't freeze constants in Ruby, only objects.

Comment: @Benjamin: I think what Jörg is saying is that you only freeze the object referred to by the constant, not the constant itself.

Comment: @Andrew:  Ah, I misunderstood what Jörg had written.  What you said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Constants in Ruby aren't "constants".  You might as well use any other name; putting them in all caps doesn't change anything, interpreter-wise, about the object, unless you try to change the pointer's address.

If you look at it that way, the behavior is obvious and necessary; Apple is a pointer to a string object, and so is banana.  You then edit the object that banana is pointing to.  Apple is pointing to that same object, so the change is reflected there too.

Comment: Rules for accessing constants are different to that for accessing variables.