# Throw exception when re-assigning a constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, constants

I've long been aware that "constants" in Ruby (i.e., variable names that are capitalized) aren't *really* constant.  Like other programming languages, a reference to an object is the only thing stored in the variable/constant.  (Sidebar:  Ruby does have the facility to "freeze" referenced objects from being modified, which as far as I know, isn't an ability offered in many other languages.)

So here's my question:  when you re-assign a value into a constant, you get a warning like so:

```
>> FOO = 'bar'
=> "bar"
>> FOO = 'baz'
(irb):2: warning: already initialized constant FOO
=> "baz"
```

Is there a way to force Ruby to throw an exception instead of printing a warning?  It's tough to figure out why reassignments happen sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [Can you ask ruby to treat warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660737/can-you-ask-ruby-to-treat-warnings-as-errors) to see how it is possible in some cases to treat warnings as errors.

Otherwise I guess you'd have to write a custom method to assign constants and raise the exception if already assigned.

If you know that a reassignment happens to a specific constant, you can also add a sanity check just before the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other question -- I wouldn't have thought about using `Kernel.warn` for that.  It doesn't look like the constant reassignment uses it though.

Comment: I didn't really try it; but I can imagine that constant assignments could be part of the language itself and thus handle in the C code. In which case it'd be even harder to hook into that, let alone raise a Ruby exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can't intercept it directly, no.

If you *really* need to do this, I can think of a very dirty hack, though. You could redirect the standard error IO to a custom IO object. The `write` method could then check for what is being written; if it contains `"warning: already initialized constant"`, then you raise, otherwise you forward the call to the standard error's `write`.

Comment: This would actually kind of work. *Very* creative approach, though ;)

Comment: Actually, that's basically what the great answer you point to is saying... We must have posted about the same time, because I hadn't read it when I posted.

Answer (score 1):

If the constant is within a class or a module, then you could `freeze` the class or module:

```
# Normal scenario
$VERBOSE = true
class Foo
  BAR = 1
end

Foo::BAR = 2 # warning: already initialized constant BAR
# Using freeze
Foo.freeze
Foo::BAR = 3
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Class
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

For your scenario, you could freeze `Object`, but that sounds kind of scary.