# Ruby Constants is there a way to have real constants ..?

Tags: ruby, syntax, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Throw exception when re-assigning a constant in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023617/throw-exception-when-re-assigning-a-constant-in-ruby)

When we use a capital letter word in ruby, it is a constant: `CONSTANT = "alive"`. When I modify this "supposed" constant, it gives an error, but modifies it anyway:

`(irb):27: warning  already initialized constant CONSTANT
=> "13"`.

This seems like an odd behavior. If I am designing a game and need a value to be constant, say: `Cheatcode_health = true`, and by accident, the value gets assigned as `false` or `0`, it would be an unusual behavior. There could be lot of implications. In short is there a true constant in Ruby?

Comment: If it hurts when you do that, don't do that.

Comment: Please put punctuations, and do capitalizations correctly. It was hard to see where the sentence ends.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a very permissive language. There's no way to raise an error if you re-assign a constant.

The only workaround is to create a custom method to assign values to constants and have this method do the check for you.

Other related questions:

- [Throw exception when re-assigning a constant in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023617/throw-exception-when-re-assigning-a-constant-in-ruby)
- [Can you ask ruby to treat warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660737/can-you-ask-ruby-to-treat-warnings-as-errors)

Comment: This Question is a duplicate ... yes how do i close this question

Comment: @pankaj: you need 3000 reputation to vote to close questions. Don't worry about it, we'll close it eventually.