# Ruby - Forbid constants redefinition

Tags: ruby, constants, redefinition

redefining some constant in Ruby (ex. `FOO = 'bar'`) generates the warning `already initialized constant`.

I'm trying to write a sort of `ReallyConstants` module, where this code should have this behaviour:

```
ReallyConstants.define_constant(:FOO, 'bar') #=> sets the constant ReallyConstants::FOO to 'bar'
ReallyConstants::FOO #=> 'bar'
ReallyConstants::FOO = 'foobar' #=> this should raise an Exception
```

that is, constant redefinition should generate an exception.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Throw exception when re-assigning a constant in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023617/throw-exception-when-re-assigning-a-constant-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just scope your constant within a module and then use `Module#freeze` to prohibit further modification of the module.

E.g.

```
module Really
  CONSTANT = :foo
  freeze
end

Really::CONSTANT = :bar
-> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Module
```

Note that this doesn't speak to the mutability of the value assigned to the constant.  For that, use `Object#freeze`.

This approach will bite you hard in environments where your code is reloaded, like in a Rails application.  There, you'll have to jump through an additional hoop, checking whether the module has been defined yet before defining it.

Generally, defensive programming in Ruby is more trouble than it's worth. What's your concern?

Comment: My purposes are mainly didactic; I'm writing a CONST module by which you can define a constant (with `CONST[:FOO] = 'bar'`), and it will define an internal constant `CONST::FOO` and an identical Object constant `Object::FOO`, and I want to keep them identical (but I don't know how to do it yet :-/ )