# In Ruby, $? is a 'read-only' variable that can't be directly assigned to. Any idea how I can do this for my own custom variable/class?

Tags: ruby, security

The issue I am faced with is that I need to prevent a Ruby class from being manipulated after it is defined. I can freeze it, but that doesn't stop people from just overwriting it all together.

I realize that some will want to respond with some sort of "Ruby isn't meant to be used like this" mantra. I get it, but my case is very special. This is for codewars.com where user submitted solutions are combined with a custom test framework, so I need to stop the user-submitted code from tinkering with the Test class.

I had thought that it wasn't possible at all to make constants true constants, but I noticed that the $? global variable is like this. Its likely that its because its built-in to the language to be like this and not something that can be done with custom variables.

Comment: $? ? You went too far. Take a look at `true`, `false` and `nil`. These guys cannot be assigned.

Comment: If you want to keep your class safe from manipulations - just define it AFTER you parse all user code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is built into the language.

In Ruby there is no way to truly define a constant. The closest you can come is writing custom getters/setters and throwing an error if a variable has already been set.

[Throw exception when re-assigning a constant in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023617/throw-exception-when-re-assigning-a-constant-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

This is defined as "The status of the last executed child process." so, if you assign something to that variable, it will be immediately overwritten by the language with the result of the last (your) assignation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about a custom implementation - perhaps extracted into some helper gem?

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(foo)
  if defined?(@foo)
    warn "warning: already initialized foo"
  else
    @foo = foo
  end
end

self.foo = :bar
puts foo            # => bar
self.foo = :baz     # => warning: already initialized foo
puts foo            # => bar
```