# Why assigned to variable constant is updated

Tags: ruby, constants

Why when I assign constant to variable and update it, constant is being updated to? Is it expected behavior or bug?

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > A = { :test => '123' }
 => {:test=>"123"} 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > b = A
 => {:test=>"123"} 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > b[:test] = '456'
 => "456" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :004 > A
 => {:test=>"456"}
```

Comment: Note that this also shows that "constants" in Ruby are not actually enforced to be constant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constant Assignment Bug in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010768/constant-assignment-bug-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected behavior, but *why* isn't always obvious. This is a very important distinction in languages like Ruby. There are three things in play here:

1. The constant `A`
2. The variable `b`
3. The hash `{ :test => '123' }`

The first two are both kinds of *variables*. The third is an *object*. The difference between variables and objects is crucial. Variables just *refer to* objects. When you assign the same object to two variables, they both refer to the same object. There was only ever one object created, so when you change it, both variables refer to the changed object.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the shallow copy mechanism. In your example A and b are actually references to the same object. To avoid that use:

```
b = A.dup
```

This will initialize b with a copy of A instead of pointing it to the same hash(i.e. this uses deep copy).

For more info see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) what shallow and deep copy is.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: It's probably not good that this answer doesn't mention references at all.